# Update with order by in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Have this table:

```
ID      SEQ     C2      C3      C4      C5

359     1       287     1       2       1

360     1       287     1       1       1

361     2       287     1       2       1

362     2       287     1       1       1

363     4       287     1       2       1

368     4       287     1       2       1

369     5       287     1       1       1

370     7       287     1       2       1 

371     4       287     1       1       1

372     6       287     1       2       1
```

And want to update only the `SEQ` column to this output:

```
ID      SEQ     C2      C3      C4      C5 

359     1       287     1       2       1

360     1       287     1       1       1

361     2       287     1       2       1

362     2       287     1       1       1

363     3       287     1       2       1

368     4       287     1       2       1

369     3       287     1       1       1

370     5       287     1       2       1

371     4       287     1       1       1

372     6       287     1       2       1
```

Column c2, c3, c4, c5 defines a service. Column SEQ defines the version, ID=361 is a new version of service defined in ID 359.

It `order by` columns `C2`, `C3`, `C4`, `C5`, and removes the gap in sequence (`SEQ` column).

Thanks

Comment: Can you please share what query you have tried?

Comment: *Why* would you *want* to do *that*?

Comment: SET @rownumber = 0;
update table t set t.SEQ = (@rownumber:=@rownumber+1)
order by  t.C2, t.C3, t.C4, t.C5, t.seq;
Order SEQ column, but dont order colum by order (t.C2, t.C3, t.C4, t.C5)

Comment: I have this system that creat this gaps, and the client want this to be fix. System dont work with gaps in seq column, and i need to fix directly in database.

Comment: Consider removing the seq column from the table. Generally, it's not a great idea to store data that can be easily derived from other stored data. (Although, I have to confess that I cannot see the sequence logic in your example!) Also, any time you have columns named something_1 through something_n, alarm bells should start ringing re normalization.

Comment: Column c2, c3, c4, c5 defines a service. Column SEQ defines the version, ID=361 is a new version of service define in ID 359.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done!

SET @rownumber = 0;

update table t set t.SEQ = (if(t.seq<@rownumber,@rownumber:=1,@rownumber:=@rownumber+1))
order by t.C2, t.C3, t.C4, t,C5, t.SEQ;